# How to plot discrete fourier graph of frequency spectrum

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, fft

I am trying to plot the frequnecy spectrum of my wav file data. I get a list of complex numbers and by testing with smaller numbers, I know the values are correct. But, I don't know how to plot. I just know I am supposed to get something like small barcharts, that are supposed be symmetrical. But my graph it's not. Below is my code and current plot.

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

df = read('matches-4.wav')
data = np.array(df[1], dtype=float)[:, 1][2000:2512]  # using right channel


def discrete_fourier_transformation():
    c = []
    for k in data:
        summation = 0
        for j in data:
            summation += j * math.e ** (-1j * (2 * math.pi / len(data)) * j * k)
        c.append(abs(1 / len(data) * summation))
    return c


values = discrete_fourier_transformation()
plt.plot(values)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: First you should have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft.

Comment: Second, not sure what you mean above.  Can you point to an example fo the kind of chart you are trying to make?  I mostly see power spectra plotted as log-log, but you sometimes see log-linear, or linear-linear as you've done...

Comment: I second Jody, why aren't you using Numpy's `fft` submodule:`import numpy.fft as fft`, is there any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the expected symmetry out of your graph because of a problem in your implementation of the Discrete Fourier Transformation.

More specifically, in your Discrete Fourier Transformation implementation the complex exponential should include multiplication by integer factors, which I imagine is what you tried to do with `j` and `k`. However the way you configured your loops the `j` and `k` values are the actual data values. To fix this you should update your loops to go over the `range(0,len(data)` range with the following:

```
def discrete_fourier_transformation():
    c = []
    for k in range(0,len(data)):
        summation = 0
        for j in range(0,len(data)):
            summation += data[j] * math.e ** (-1j * (2 * math.pi / len(data)) * j * k)
        c.append(abs(1 / len(data) * summation))
    return c
```